# createElement, appendChild performance worst in loop

Tags: javascript, performance, dom

I have a A-Tag with a innerText and want to replace that with 2 new Tags, one DIV-Tag with the text of the A's innerText and the other tag is a 'I'-Tag which is appended after the DIV-Tag:

before:

```
<a>hello world</>
```

after:

```
<a>
 <div>hello world</div>
 <i></i>
</a>
```

I have two alternatives which both works:

**1. Way:**

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('#mytags a');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    node_a = items[i];
    var txt_a = node_a.innerText;
    var txt_span = document.createElement('div');
    txt_span.innerHTML = txt_a;
    node_a.innerText = '';
    node_a.appendChild(txt_span);

    var icon_node = document.createElement('i');
    node_a.appendChild(icon_node);
}
```

**2. Way:**

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('#mytags a');
[].forEach.call(items, function(a) {

            var txt_a = a.innerText;
            var txt_span = document.createElement('div');
            txt_span.innerHTML = txt_a;
            a.innerText = '';
            a.appendChild(txt_span);

            var icon_node = document.createElement('i');
            a.appendChild(icon_node);
        });
```

Both works, however, the performance is really bad when having only about 50 A-Tags. How can I make this faster?

For example, when rendering in Safari or Firefox, there is a time lag of 1-2 seconds when rendering the content of the I-tags. The content of the I-Tag is associated by a css class:

```
#mytags a>i:after{
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';

    content: '\f054';
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 20px;
}
```

The question is, are my loops the fastest way or what is the reason for the time lag? I have no more than 50 A-Tags.

Comment: Why exactly do you need it done dynamically? Seems to me, like you could use one of the libraries out there and make a custom component for it, if you really need something like this.

Comment: Maybe, the problem lies with querySelectorAll (because it returns no live nodes). I don't know. However, I cannot replace that with getElementById('mytags'), because #myTags has different depth of childNodes and these childNodes can have A-tags.

Comment: I'm confused: what's the question about? The slow performance of both methods, as its body implies, or the first one (the loop), as the header does?

Comment: Also, not sure why do you use `innerText` property and not `innerHTML` (or even `Node.removeChild` in a loop).

Comment: Change `innerText` to `textContent`, and I get  50x performance boost.

Comment: Gosh, squint, you are absolutly right. That was the reason! Now, no time lag occurs. Thank you very much!

Comment: raina77ow: because innerHtml would return nested node-elements inside which I do not need.

Comment: I guess, there is no performance difference of the two loops. The reason was innerText and innerHtml. I guess, there is no other way to better the performance of the result.

Comment: Yeah, I think there's not much else there to improve WRT execution speed. Only thing I'd do would be to reduce the code a little by getting rid of some of the unnecessary variable assignments. https://jsfiddle.net/8p80yg8g/

Comment: thank you again. You are right, in this case is shorter better;)

Comment: @nimo23 I was talking about `a.innerText = ` part. But yes, getting `textContent` should be way faster as well.

Comment: `txt_a = a.innerText; .... txt_span.innerHTML = txt_a;` you're converting text to html, bad idea. and you should be transplanting the child nodes, not strings.

Comment: Thanks. I have already changed it to div.textContent = txt_a. Transplanting child nodes is not a good idea in this case, because I want to create two nodes within the actual element and one node contains the textContent of txt_a.t.